# HTML5 Canvas RTL for Individual Texts

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bidi

I have a `<canvas>` on which I want to render right-to-left strings (e.g. Hebrew sentence with some English words somewhere in the middle).

For the whole canvas, a `dir` attribute may be specified. So, in my example I'd use `<canvas dir="rtl />`.

Unfortunately, this solution is far from being complete. I have some sentences in the same application that are LTR (for example, English only, or English with some Hebrew at the middle, but not the opposite).

- Is there any way to specify `dir` per string basis, without using two or more `<canvas>`es?

Here's a naive example of how the `dir` attribute chages that way the `canvas` handles bidirectional strings:

```js
var text = 'קצת text בעברית'

var rtlCanvas = document.getElementById('rtl-canvas')
var rtlCtx = rtlCanvas.getContext('2d')
rtlCtx.font = '24px Arial'
rtlCtx.fillText(text, 250, 50)

var ltrCanvas = document.getElementById('ltr-canvas')
var ltrCtx = ltrCanvas.getContext('2d')
ltrCtx.font = '24px Arial'
ltrCtx.fillText(text, 0, 50)
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Looking good with dir=rtl:</p>
  <canvas id="rtl-canvas" dir="rtl" width=300 height=100/>
</div>

<div>
  <p>With dir=ltr, first and last words are swapped</p>
  <canvas id="ltr-canvas" dir="ltr" width=300 height=100/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try and wrap each Hebrew string in  a span and then add it a class with a style of `direction: rtl;` ?

Comment: It's `canvas`. There is no DOM. There are no `span`s (or CSS, etc.)

Comment: Can you please try and add a code snippet?

Comment: It'd be pointless. I'm asking about features of `canvas`, not about troubleshooting some specific piece of code.

Comment: Nevertheless, I did an an example just to clarify things.

Comment: I only found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/direction which I assumed you tried. In case you haven't maybe it can help. You can change the value before every text you draw. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually this is really smart, I haven't thought about changing the attribute on the fly! If you'd submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the direction per string by changing the `dir` attribute programmatically as needed:

```js
var text = 'קצת text בעברית'
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.font = '24px Arial'
ctx.fillText(text, 165, 50)

canvas.setAttribute('dir','ltr');
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 100)
```

```html
   
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" dir="rtl" width=300 height=300/>
</div>
```

Comment: how to justify?