# I have a problem with numbers when writing them, their place changes from the text when using the Arabic language

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, arabic, pdfdocument

I have a problem with numbers when writing them, their place changes from the text when using the Arabic language
Note that in the case of writing in English, no error occurs

[image]

```
TextPaint mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout( textToSave ,mTextPaint, canvas.getWidth() - 100, 
Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
canvas.save();
int textX = 50;
int textY = 50;
canvas.translate(textX, textY);

mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have written it well formatted in your xml string

Comment: Written correctly, when I use the English language, this error does not occur, but when I use the Arabic language, this happens

Comment: can you past your arabic string here

Comment: I don't understand can you explain?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500907/html5-canvas-rtl-for-individual-texts

Comment: it should be helpful

Comment: I have same problem .. any solution?